# Detecting clicked horizontal position in a div

Tags: javascript, css

When i click on streaming bar, position will be detected from left edge of the browser window but it has to be detected from left edge of the `#progressBar` div in this **[demo](http://www.olmasigereken.com/demo3/)**. So, because of positioning `#progressBar` div with `left: 200px;` 200px is added on horizontal position that is clicked.

My simple detecting function:

```
function point_it(e){
      var x=e.clientX; 
      var seekSecond = Math.floor((x/1100) * ytplayer.getDuration()); //1100 is width of the progress bar 
      seekTo(seekSecond);
      document.getElementById("xPos").innerHTML=x;
    }
```

style:

```
    #progressBar{
position: relative;
top: 400px;
left: 200px;
width: 1100px;
height: 4px;
border: 2px solid gray;
margin: 10px;
z-index: 8;
}


#elapsedBar{
position: relative;
top: -1px;
width:0px;
height:3px;
border:1px solid;
border-color: #660033;
background-color: #660033;
margin:0px;
z-index: 10;
}

#loadedBar{
position: relative;
top: 0px;
width: 0px;
height:4px;
border:1px solid;
border-color: gray;
background-color: gray;
margin:0px;
z-index: 9;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the exact issue here?

Comment: If you click left edge of the streaming bar you will see that it jumps second 11 instead of 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subtract the left position from the clicked position, I only know the jQuery way of doing this:

```
// Get the "left" value
var leftPos = $("#progressBar").css("left");
// Remove "px"
var leftPos = leftPos.replace("px", "");
```

Then subtract `leftPos` from the value you are getting

Comment: I upgrade these code using `$(window).width();` So, i can say that it solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `e.offsetX` in your function instead of `e.clientX`.

`e.client...` is related to the browsers window, `e.offsett...` is related to the clicked target element.

Answer (score 1):

You have to subtract 10 from `x` because of `margin: 10px;`. This causes `var x=e.clientX;` to be 10 when clicking on the left side of the bar.